# Issue in showing time of a date field in MVC view / partial class.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, date-formatting

I am developing a MVC application.
I am trying to display date time in the view.

I have write below code in partial class of the entity.

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt} ")]
   public System.DateTime CommentDateTime { get; set; }
```

but its not working....
only date get displayed like

> 11 Mar 2013

I am interstedin

> 11 Mar 2013    01:40 PM

How to do this ?

Comment: you want to display in textbox or as a text. if you simply want to display "DisplayFor" is good enough

Comment: Add the code how you are attempting to print the CommentDateTime in your view and it will be easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

What control you're using to display the annotated DateTime?

`[DisplayFormat]` is used only when using [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or [DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) control. If you use it on a normal `TextBox` or similar then you need to find other solution.